# Rotation matrix problem, besides rotation my object gets translated too

Tags: opengl

Rotation matrix problem, besides rotation my object gets translated too.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();   
m.SetRotate(new Vector(0, 0, 1), Math.PI / 4);  
m.PrintMatrix();    
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)    
{  
_spaceship.VertexPositions[i] *= m;  
}
```

1. I create an identity matrix.
2. SetRotate makes it a rotation matrix, for rotation pi/4 around z axis.
3. I printed more matrices to check if SetRotate does work, it does indeed, so SetRotate does it's job well, something else must be causing the problem.
4. _spaceship is a sprite with 6 vertices(two triangles), and each of them i multiply with the rotation matrix. VertexPositions stores Vectors for each vertex position.

So the rotation matrix is fine, i have checked the vector matrix multiplication also fine, I don't understand where that extra translation could come from. My object does get rotated pi/4, but it gets translated X:-14.1421356237309, Y:-16.6170093578839, Z:0, and it is supposed to be all zeroes X:0, Y:0, Z:0 just like before the rotation.

Comment: What is the output of m.PrintMatrix();?

Comment: You show x, y, and z values; which of the six vertices do they correspond to? You might as well show the values of the six vertices before and after the rotation.

Comment: Matrix multiplication does not commute. Perhaps the *= operator is not overloaded properly for matrix multiplication?

Comment: 0.707106781186548      0.707106781186547       0
-0.707106781186547     0.707106781186548       0
0                      0                       1
0                      0                       0

Comment: The operator is fine, double checked. Those x,y,x values are for the sprite center, neither of the 6 vertices.

Comment: Why dont you use ready solutions, eg GLM?

Comment: As you are using OpenGl, matrixs are 4x4 and not 3x3, maybe a problem could come from those forgotten values.

Comment: @przemo_li: From the liberal use of `new` (and the lack of storing the results in a pointer), this is either Java or C#, not C++. And I'm guessing C#, unless Java got operator overloading since I last checked.

Answer (score 0):

Are your spaceship's vertex positions already offset? If you want to rotate your model around it's center, make sure that the model vertices are relative to the center.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to normalize your vec3 before making the rotation.